# Calcium based Corrosion-Inhibitors used in Ethanol fuel, and their effect on the organic-solvent abilities of that alcohol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

Ethanol is a good organic solvent, often the preferred non-toxic choice for the processing of plant extracts. One of the cheapest sources of Ethanol is the kind used in fireplaces and racing fuel, but this has the corrosion inhibitor DCI-11 added. DCI-11 is added to the Ethanol at a rate of 86mg/litre and is made from Calcium Nitrate (max 1-10%) and Calcium Nitrite (max 25-50%). DCI-11 "reduces the corrosion and solvent effects of the alcohol, also buffering/stabilising the pH". My question is - to what extent if any, will this reduce its use as an organic solvent for the processing of plant extracts?

Comment: I expect the purchaser can accept or reject any addition to a commodity.